# How do you print conditional debug statements from an Azure DevOps YAML file?

Tags: azure-devops

You see all of these conditional debug statements in the Azure Pipeline logs when enabling debug/diagnostics.

```
##[debug]   -NoLogo
##[debug]   -NoProfile
##[debug]   -NonInteractive
##[debug]   -Command
```

But how does one print these from a PipeLine YAML file, script, or program?
I saw examples for logging warnings and errors in the Azure PipeLines [Logging Commands Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) through powershell.

```
echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."
echo "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;sourcepath=consoleapp/main.cs;linenumber=1;columnnumber=1;code=100;]Found something that could be a problem."
```

but nothing on conditional debug verbose statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logs in Azure DevOps are parsed automatically. Check the following example:

```
# Write your powershell commands here.

Write-Host "##[section] This is colored green!"
Write-Host "##[command] This is colored blue!"
Write-Host "##[debug] This is colored gray!"
Write-Host "##[warning] This is a warning!"
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]This is another warning" 
Write-Host "##[error] This is an error!"
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]This is another error"
```

[image]

Comment: See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell